# How to filter an object from non duplicated values in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, object

I've got an array of objects where make and model properties are duplicated:

```
const mockVariants = [
  {
    variantId: '1',
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'X3',
    fuel: 'petrol',
  },
  {
    variantId: '2',
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'X3',
    fuel: 'diesel',
  },
  {
    variantId: '3',
    make: 'BMW',
    model: 'X5',
    fuel: 'petrol',
  },
  {
    variantId: '4',
    make: 'BMW',
    model: '3 Series',
    fuel: 'petrol',
  },
{
    variantId: '5',
    make: 'Volvo',
    model: 'XC60',
    fuel: 'petrol',
  },
  {
    variantId: '6',
    make: 'Volvo',
    model: 'XC60',
    fuel: 'diesel',
  },
  {
    variantId: '6',
    make: 'Volvo',
    model: 'XC60',
    fuel: 'hybrid',
  },
  {
    variantId: '7',
    make: 'Volvo',
    model: 'V70',
    fuel: 'petrol',
  }
]
```

What I would like to do is be able to perform a filter in TypeScript on the objects to return another array of objects where duplicated makes and models are reduced and the unique makes are combined with their models that are assigned to models array.

See example below:

```
const makeModels = [{
    make: 'BMW',
    models: ['X3', 'X5', '3 Series']
},
{
    make: 'Volvo',
    models: ['X60', 'V70']
},
]
```

Comment: do you need answer in javascript?

Comment: Sorry, should mention that, in TypeScript, please

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can simply reduce it.

```js
var mockVariants = [ { variantId: '1', make: 'BMW', model: 'X3', fuel: 'petrol', }, { variantId: '2', make: 'BMW', model: 'X3', fuel: 'diesel', }, { variantId: '3', make: 'BMW', model: 'X5', fuel: 'petrol', }, { variantId: '4', make: 'BMW', model: '3 Series', fuel: 'petrol', },{ variantId: '5', make: 'Volvo', model: 'XC60', fuel: 'petrol', }, { variantId: '6', make: 'Volvo', model: 'XC60', fuel: 'diesel', }, { variantId: '6', make: 'Volvo', model: 'XC60', fuel: 'hybrid', }, { variantId: '7', make: 'Volvo', model: 'V70', fuel: 'petrol', }]

var result = Object.values(mockVariants.reduce((acc,{make,model})=>{
   acc[make] = acc[make] || { make, models:[] };
   acc[make].models = [...new Set([...acc[make].models,model])];
   return acc;
},{} as any));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited my post, I should mention that I'm working in TypeScript

Comment: It's complaining about acc[make], saying:

var make: string | undefined
Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.

No idea how to fix it

Comment: @dariusz in reduce in the last line make sure you define type of accumulator. so here you can do something like `},{} as any));`(I have made the change in answer). If not work then you might have to include the `es2019` support in your ts file.